# Hiding Rows with No Data in Multiple Areas on a Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have recently just got this code working;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Range("G24:G71,N24:N71")
        Dim r As Long: For r = 1 To .Areas(1).Rows.Count
            Dim bHide As Boolean: bHide = True
            Dim xArea As Range: For Each xArea In .Areas
                If IsEmpty(xArea.Cells(r, 1).Value) = False Then
                    bHide = False
                End If
            Next xArea
            .Rows(r).EntireRow.Hidden = bHide
        Next r
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

However, I would like the code to look at multiple areas. I have tried the following and it is not working;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Range("G24:G71,N24:N71")
        Dim r As Long: For r = 1 To .Areas(1).Rows.Count
            Dim bHide As Boolean: bHide = True
            Dim xArea As Range: For Each xArea In .Areas
                If IsEmpty(xArea.Cells(r, 1).Value) = False Then
                    bHide = False
                End If
            Next xArea
            .Rows(r).EntireRow.Hidden = bHide
        Next r
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Range("G81:G124,N81:N124")
        Dim r As Long: For r = 1 To .Areas(1).Rows.Count
            Dim bHide As Boolean: bHide = True
            Dim xArea As Range: For Each xArea In .Areas
                If IsEmpty(xArea.Cells(r, 1).Value) = False Then
                    bHide = False
                End If
            Next xArea
            .Rows(r).EntireRow.Hidden = bHide
        Next r
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I get the following Error message;

> Compile Error: Ambiguous name detected: Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate.

It also highlights the first line of the second string of code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Apologies I forgot to add the error message. Edited.

Comment: So the issue is that you cannot have more than one of the same event for the same sheet. You need to combine your two pieces of code into one.

Comment: Any ideas on how that can be done. I have given it a try and can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Could you not just put the 2nd With clause straight after the first? You might have to reset bHide in the middle. Or just extend your range `With Range("G24:G71,N24:N71,G81:G124,N81:N124")`.

Comment: What do you mean by resetting bHide? I have tried extending the range but i think because there is blank rows in cells 72:81 (which i do not want hidden) it does not work. I think it needs to stand as two separate arguments.

Comment: I just mean `bhide=true` in the middle so doesn't inherit previous value. What happens if G81 is empty but N81 isn't? Or can't that happen?

Comment: That can happen. Below is my previous post which lead to the above code (the first part of code). It had to be changed to area to account for the differences in ranges in Column G & N.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023241/hiding-rows-based-on-different-column-data-ranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work, assuming your code functions as you intend currently.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Range("G24:G71,N24:N71")
        Dim r As Long: For r = 1 To .Areas(1).Rows.Count
            Dim bHide As Boolean: bHide = True
            Dim xArea As Range: For Each xArea In .Areas
                If IsEmpty(xArea.Cells(r, 1).Value) = False Then
                    bHide = False
                End If
            Next xArea
            .Rows(r).EntireRow.Hidden = bHide
        Next r
    End With
    With Range("G81:G124,N81:N124")
        For r = 1 To .Areas(1).Rows.Count
            bHide = True
            For Each xArea In .Areas
                If IsEmpty(xArea.Cells(r, 1).Value) = False Then
                    bHide = False
                End If
            Next xArea
            .Rows(r).EntireRow.Hidden = bHide
        Next r
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you for your time!